# BT_SCAN config in Zephyr project - is this required for scanning? No

Tags: zephyr-rtos, nordic-semi, nrf-connect

I have a project where a BLE device connects to another (very innovative, right?) As part of this it obviously scans. The whole thing actually functions pretty good. But now I have just got to know about a config called CONFIG_BT_SCAN. I have no idea what it does, I did not have it enabled and the help hover-over says "Enable BLE scan library". Who would have guessed, right? The [NordicSemi documentation](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/1.9.2-dev1/kconfig/CONFIG_BT_SCAN.html) does not say one word more. One thing I know is that it is **NOT** required for scanning, my project scans just fine without it.

To sum up the question again: How does one learn about these thing? How does one find out that this config exists? How to find documentation about what it does?

Comment: There is a simple answer to your questions: The truth is in the code.

Comment: @Risto excuse me, are you suggesting to learn a framework like Zephyr by reading through the source code? Is it how you do that? This is what documentation is for. But this thing doesn't have any. Do you actually know what that config does? Because if you do, you might as well answer the question. :D I honestly don't know the answer and would love to hear it!

Comment: Yes, that's my suggestion. Like all open source projects, Zephyr lives from the people who participate and create documentation, for example. As long as nobody has the motivation to document this switch, it will stay that way. 
And to be honest, that's the most fun part. Reading and understanding other people's source code is what has helped me the most as a programmer.

Comment: This is where fun gets washed together with work. I agree it is fun to read other people's code, but this is playing with stuff. I need to program microcontrollers for work and Zephyr is one tool from the 20 I use. I need to get something done and not reverse engineer my tools. I wonder then, what is the professional equivalent of Zephyr, what is ready to work with, documented and reliable?

Comment: If you are unable to devote the necessary effort to getting your work done, [perhaps there is a company](https://zephyrproject.org/ecosystem-vendor-offerings/) you can hire to do it for you?

Comment: I don't look at the RTOS as part of my work, I look at it like a tool, like a browser. I also use a browser for work. I don't want to write one, I expect it to be there in a reliable working order. When working with AVR controllers (Atmel times) the documentation, the controller specific header files and the compiler are given. I only use them. NordicSemi used to have the nRF5 SDK, then they decided to switch to nRF Connect, which is Zephyr based. So they have decided for me to use Zephyr - which would be fine unless I have to develop Zephyr now.

Comment: And again, I have no problem with contributing time to time to open source projects, I understand how it works. My problem now is that the option to "just use it" is not really there due to the (almost) complete lack of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> How does one learn about these thing?

The nRF Connect SDK has a set of samples under ncs/nrf/samples/bluetooth and ncs/zephyr/samples/bluetooth. I typically see how the samples do things when I am trying to learn.
Nordic Semiconductor also has a introduction course to Bluetooth Low Energy developement over at https://academy.nordicsemi.com/courses/bluetooth-low-energy-fundamentals/

> How does one find out that this config exists?

From samples mentioned above. Or from looking for CONFIG_BT in Nordics Kconfig search: https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/kconfig/index.html

> How to find documentation about what it does?

https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/kconfig/index.html#CONFIG_BT_SCAN

Or at ncs/nrf/subsys/bluetooth/Kconfig.scan.
Or by using menuconfig (west build -t menuconfig") and search for BT_SCAN with "/".
Or if you are using nRF Connect Extension for VS Code, you can use the Kconfig action.